# iPhone Pop-Up Keypad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Okay I'm trying to have a custom keypad pop-up when I want to enter information.  I'm thinking the keypad can be a view itself and just pop-up when the user wants to enter information.  Any ideas or suggestions.  I'm looking for something similar to the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this, assuming myKeyboardViewController is a View Controller that handles a view called myView:

```
myTextField.inputView = myKeyboardViewController.myView;
```

You can then create the view in interface builder.

Comment: But won't my view be full screen or can I customize the size of the view to be half a screen long

Comment: You can set the view frame in myKeyboardViewController

Comment: Would you by chance, have an example?

Comment: This is the correct way you have to follow to reach the results you want. I haven't got any example.